# Testing Asynchrounous Mule Flow using FunctionalTestCase

Tags: testing, mule, junit4, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a flow like:

```
<flow name='main_flow'>
.....
<vm://out_bound-endpoint1 />
<flow-ref name='sub-flow1'/> 
</flow>

<sub-flow name='sub-flow1'>
<cxf://endpoint/>
</sub-flow>
```

Here 'vm://endpoint1>' is one way and flow is async

How to Test end-to-end.
Using 'muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct('sub-flow1')
giving cast Exception.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish an end-to-end test here, I would need to know what happens to the message after it is dispatched to the VM queue.  Presumably, there is another flow that consumes that endpoint and does something more.

My end-to-end test would initiate a message to the transport that is the message source for this flow, and then monitor and assert on the flow that receives the message from the VM queue.

Answer (score 1):

To do an end-to-end test you need to include in your test the starting point of the flow as it would work in production, this is, you need to make your inbound endpoint to run, calling it or making it read some value. Then verify that all the systems are impacted as expected, in your case you should go and see if your WS received the correct request.

I recommend you to use JUnit to make the setup and verification, but I cannot help on how to trigger the flow execution or how can you validate the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly test a sub-flow in mule. This is not supported as of now.

Refer to the following stackoverflow post which provides more detials.

[Testing sub-flows in Mule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717131/testing-sub-flows-in-mule)

Comment: Thanks, at least can I capture the response payload from the subflow when an event happens by using eventCallback, latch etc.

Comment: As you might know subflow is a kind of code embedded into your flow the EventCallback will not help in capturingthe response received from the subflow.

Comment: @shrinathM Where are you with this issue? Have you got it working?